# Toggle li .active class

Tags: jquery, toggle

The li .active toggle in the following fiddle doesn't work. When i delete  id="Colour54" in the input element, it works.

Why is that? And how can i make this work.

```
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f0r8xd9b/1/

Comment: Mark your chosen answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, because the event bubbles, the function is called twice, so the class is toggled and then untoggled again in the same instant.

You can fix this in JavaScript, but I would rather suggest this CSS-only solution:

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label {
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <input id="Colour54" onclick="processFilter();" type="checkbox" name="1[Value][][@id]" value="54" />
        <label for="Colour54" style="font-weight: normal;">zwart</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

There is a small difference though, since that solution styles just the label, not the li. So here is the fix in your version:

```js
$( "input[type='checkbox']" ).click(function(event) {
  $("ul li").toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

.active{
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <input id="Colour54" onclick="processFilter();" type="checkbox" name="1[Value][][@id]" value="54" />
        <label for="Colour54" style="font-weight: normal;">zwart</label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Basically, it binds the click event handler to the checkbox. This way it is executed when you toggle the checkbox (also when you click the label).

Answer (score 0):

You are targeting the wrong element. In your 1st fiddle if you click on the bullet it works just fine.

https://jsfiddle.net/f0r8xd9b/12/

I changed your jQuery Code to this:

```
$( "ul li label").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
```

Comment: Absolutely no need to repeat the same jQuery selector. Inside the function, it's available as `$(this)`.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because your click event on the label bubbles to the list item, plus it's attached to your checkbox input. This triggers your function twice, thus toggling to and fro at once. Do you really need the `<li>`to be listening to `click`, or the `label`?

And you don't need Javascript at all for this usecase. Use CSS!

```
:checked + label {
    color: red;
}
```

If for some weird reason you insist on using jQuery, here you go (quick and dirty solution):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("ul li").on("click", function(event) {
        if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase()=="label") { $(this).toggleClass("active"); }
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/f0r8xd9b/11/